# Laravel Restricting access for development site

Tags: laravel

We are migrating our site to laravel 5 from a custom frame created a while ago... We have a production site as well as a development site. Is there a easy solution for restricting access to the development site at all times unless they meet certain circumstances?

I'm interest in one of the following methods:

- Unrestricting based on IP
- Unrestricting based on Login

The solution I'm looking for is something I'd like to not have to change when uploading from development to production and would like it to follow the following logic if possible:

```
if(liveSite){
    Show everything, no restrictions
}elseif(developmentSite){
    Hide everything, unrestrict based on logic
}
```

We currently do this with separate .htaccess files but i'd prefer not to have to keep track of two separate files and overwriting possibities

Comment: Yes it does- you just have to implement them.

Comment: Any idea where I can find that information? Everything I find is based on "maintenance" and app:down() or restricts routing to just certain pages.

Comment: You need to use authentication middlewear: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication and disable registration once you have your user before deploying in public

Comment: If access restriction is environment-specific, then it would make more sense to do this at the server level (i.e. white-list IP ranges in a **.htaccess** or similar configuration file) rather than putting conditionals in your application’s codebase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) for that and use the currently configured environment, request IP and the authentication system to restrict access. First create the middleware by running:

```
php artisan make:middleware DevelopmentAccess
```

Then in the new `app/Http/Middleware/DevelopmentAccess.php` file, you add the following logic:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class DevelopmentAccess
{
    /**
     * Client IPs allowed to access the app.
     * Defaults are loopback IPv4 and IPv6 for use in local development.
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $ipWhitelist = ['127.0.0.1', '::1'];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (app()->environment() != 'production' && $this->clientNotAllowed()) {
            return abort(403, 'You are not authorized to access this');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if current request client is allowed to access the app.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function clientNotAllowed()
    {
        $isAllowedIP = in_array(request()->ip(), $this->ipWhitelist);

        return (!$isAllowedIP && auth()->guest())
            || ($isAllowedIP && !auth()->guest());
    }
}
```

Register the middleware it in the kernel's `$routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    'dev' => \App\Http\Middleware\DevelopmentAccess::class,
];
```

Then you restrict the routes accordingly:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'dev'], function()
{
    // All routes that need restricting for non-approved clients go here
});

// Routes that need access such as "login" go outside the group
get('/login', 'SessionController@login');
```

The logic is simple: if the environment is not `production` (not live) and either the user IP is whitelisted or the user is authenticated then they have access.

Comment: your solution is nice. +

Comment: Thank you so much for this well written solution!